# Arbitrary Length Input in C

Tags: performance, c, heap

From `scanf()` to `fgets()`, we need to first specify the maximum length of the string input, due to which input gets a limitation, which isn't that good. As input can vary from **[0, ∞)**, due to computer limitation input will never reach ∞, but it can be very large.

I have seen in C++, there no limit for string input.

```cpp
std::string x;
std::cin >> x;
```

So, to implement this feature in C, I have created a function which takes a single character from the user and appends it at the last of the buffer, after that it calls `realloc()` for the buffer.

##### Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline void exit_heap_fail(const void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "err: null-pointer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static char *input(void)
{
    char *ptr = calloc(2, sizeof(char)), ch;
    exit_heap_fail(ptr);
    size_t len = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()))
    {
        if (ch == 10 || ch == 0)
            break;
        ptr[len++] = ch;
        ptr = realloc(ptr, len + 1);
        exit_heap_fail(ptr);
    }
    ptr[len] = 0;
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    puts("Enter:");
    char *data = input();
    printf("DATA = `%s`\n", data);
    free(data);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) ?

Comment: Note that `getline()` is not part of the Standard C library although its functional design is worth reviewing as a guide here.

Comment: getline() is a part of the Dynamic Allocation Functions TR and POSIX too, however

Comment: As you note `std::string` is also limited by the computer's memory.

Comment: @qwr But it can be appended, and its limit isn't assigned by the programmer

Comment: So your goal is a `scanf` that can go up to a computer's memory without unnecessarily allocating a huge buffer of space if not needed I assume?

Comment: @qwr Yes, you got it right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**End-of-file**

When nothing is read, code returns an allocated `""`.  That is indistinguishable from reading only a `'\n'` as that returns `""` too.

To function like other standard input functions, code should return some indication, like `NULL`:

- No input and end-of-file reported.
- Input error occurs, regardless is anything read.

**Infinite loop**

When end-of-file occurs `getchar()` returns `EOF` and code never exits the loop.

```
// Infinite loop
while ((ch = getchar())) {
    if (ch == 10 || ch == 0)
        break;
```

**Redundant test**

Code test for the *null character* twice.

**257**

`getchar()` returns 257 different values (`EOF` and all `unsigned char`).  Saving that in a `char` loses information.

Use `int ch`.

**Repetitive calls to re-allocate**

`realloc(ptr, len + 1);` calls `realloc()` every iteration.  A more efficient common approach approximately doubles the size each loop with a right-size allocation in the end.

**Ending input on a *null character***

This is different from `fgets(), scanf()`.

---

[Edit]

Some sample code to illustrate these ideas and a few more.  Only lightly tested.
Header:

```
/* 
 * Allocate as needed to form a string from user input.
 *
 * Return NULL on
 * * End of file with no input
 * * Input error
 * * Out of memory
 * Caller to use feof(), ferror() to distinguish.
 *
 * Otherwise return allocated buffer.
 * Caller to free buffer.
 */
char* line_alloc(void);
```

Source

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_ALLOC_MIN 63  /* Some power-of-2 minus 1 */

static char* line_alloc_helper(char *buf, size_t *len_max_ptr) {
  // Is input longer than supportable size?
  if (*len_max_ptr > SIZE_MAX / 2 - 1) {
    free(buf);
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t sz = *len_max_ptr + 1;  // Old buffer size
  sz = 2 * sz + 1;               // New buffer size
  if (sz < LINE_ALLOC_MIN) {
    sz = LINE_ALLOC_MIN;
  }
  char *buf_new = realloc(buf, sz);
  if (buf_new == NULL) {
    free(buf);
    return NULL;
  }
  *len_max_ptr = sz - 1;
  return buf_new;
}

char* line_alloc(void) {
  size_t len = 0;
  size_t len_max = 0;
  char *buf = NULL;
  int ch;
  bool nothing_read = true;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    nothing_read = false;
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0') { // Remove ch == '\0' if desired.
      break;
    }
    if (len >= len_max) {
      buf = line_alloc_helper(buf, &len_max);
      if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
      }
    }
    buf[len++] = (char) ch;
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    if (nothing_read || !feof(stdin)) {  // Note 1
      free(buf);
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  char *buf_right_size = realloc(buf, len + 1);
  if (buf_right_size == NULL) {
    free(buf);
  } else {
    buf_right_size[len] = '\0';
  }
  return buf_right_size;
}

/* Note 1: Better as !feof() than ferror() to identify 
end-of-file with input error set from prior activity. */
```

Test:

```c
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char * buf;
    while ((buf = line_alloc()) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(buf);
        printf("%2zu <%s>\n", len, buf);
        free(buf);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Future improvements/ideas:

- Support `FILE *input_stream`.
- Might as well use local buffer, say 127 bytes, and them `malloc()` during the right-size step for short lines.  Transition to allocated buffers for *long* lines.  Adds complexity, but makes for only one allocation for common lines.
- Cope with `'\r'` `'\n'` pairs that come up from reading foreign text files.
- Provide caller with `len` to better support lines with embedded *null characters*.
- Provide an upper bound rather than `SIZE_MAX` for max line length to help prevent hacker abuse of code.